# Could not find a part of the path Asp.Net MVC 3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, file-io

I am trying to download a file stored in a folder.

```
 string path = "D:\\app_data\\Clients\\Client " + jobdescription.ClientID + "\\Job " + jobdescription.JobDescriptionID + "\\";
 string file = Path.Combine(path, jobdescription.JobTitle + ".docx");
 return File(path, "application/docx", jobdescription.JobTitle + ".docx");
```

The error generated is:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
Could not find a part of the path 'D:\app_data\Clients\Client 1\Job 2\'
```

But the file with specified filename is in the folder. What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: The path in your sample code does not match the path in the error message you posted.  Maybe you can clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use `path` instead of using `file`, in your third line.

It should read:

```
return File(file, "application/docx", jobdescription.JobTitle + ".docx");
```